# Why MYSQL still return the uncommitted record under REPEATABLE READ?

Tags: mysql

For the above query, why session 2 still can return the record 2? As session  1 haven't commit the record with value 2. 
BTW ,the transaction isolated level is REPEATABLE READ , and the tool is MYSQL workbench.

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
`C1` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`C1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


session 1
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO new_table VALUES (2)

Session 2
SELECT * FROM new_table;
```

Comment: check that auto commit is off - usually in visual tools it's on and session 1 committed automatically for you. (without you wanting to)

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem:

```sql
-- SESSION 1

mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.19    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation,
    ->   @@SESSION.tx_isolation,
    ->   @@GLOBAL.autocommit,
    ->   @@SESSION.autocommit;
+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation | @@SESSION.tx_isolation | @@GLOBAL.autocommit | @@SESSION.autocommit |
+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
| REPEATABLE-READ       | REPEATABLE-READ        |                   1 |                    1 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `new_table`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `new_table` (
    ->   `C1` INT NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`C1`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `new_table`
    -> VALUES (2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `C1`
    -> FROM `new_table`;
+----+
| C1 |
+----+
|  2 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-- SESSION 2

mysql> SELECT
    ->   @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation,
    ->   @@SESSION.tx_isolation,
    ->   @@GLOBAL.autocommit,
    ->   @@SESSION.autocommit;
+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation | @@SESSION.tx_isolation | @@GLOBAL.autocommit | @@SESSION.autocommit |
+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
| REPEATABLE-READ       | REPEATABLE-READ        |                   1 |                    1 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `C1`
    -> FROM `new_table`;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Using MySQL Workbench 6.3 (Version 6.3.6 build 511 CE (64 bits) Community):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When we open two query Windows in MYSQL workbench,  these two query Windows belong to the same session,so the issue happened.